# Test response body (properties) gives assertion error - Mocha, Chai, Node.js

Tags: node.js, api, mocha.js, integration-testing, chai

I'm using Node.js, Mocha, Chai (expect) to test API Integration. Trying to test the properties and values of the response body as detail as possible but running into assertion error.

Error received for **expect(response.body).to.have.property('Response’)**

(node:55010) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError: Target cannot be null or undefined.

**Request**: POST https://api.us-east.amazonaws.com/dev

**Request Json**

```
{
    "Request": {
        “Code:””
    } 
}
```

**Response**

```
{
    "Response": {
        "Status": false,
        "Code": "REQUIRED",
        "Description": null
    }
}
```

//Config.js

```
module.exports.ins = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://api.us-east.amazonaws.com',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Accept: 'application/json',
  },
});
```

//Post.js

```
const { ins } = require('../../utils/config);
const axios = require('axios');
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require("chai-http");
const instance = axios.create();
const { expect } = chai;
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('API Test', function () {

  it('POST returns status 200', function (done) {
    ins.post('/dev’, data).then(function (response) {
      expect(response).to.have.status(200);
      expect(response).to.be.an('object');
      expect(response.body).to.have.property('GetAllOffersResponse')
      console.log('\n Status:', response.status, response.statusText, '\n Request:', response.request.method, response.request.path, '\n Response:', '\n', response.data);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

[Error Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2rF0.png)

I'm new to this stack. any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Could you `console.log` the `response` you are trying to expect its props?

Comment: Yes I'm able to console.log the response.data

Comment: I am sorry, I meant what values do you get (see in the terminal) when you log the response ?

Comment: Sorry misread it. Attached the screenshot of the log